# Given values on a mesh, what algorithm can I use to construct efficiently level set contours?

Tags: computational-geometry, visualization

I have a mesh, faces $F$, edges $E$, and vertices $V$, and I have a list of predefined level set contours.

What algorithm can I use to construct contours in the most efficient manner?

[image]

A plot of the contour is shown above. Lines with the same color have the same $z$ value.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: not sure, it seems like a relevant question to me.  Downvoter?  One issue is that isolines don't seem particularly well-defined for mesh data.  Could you perhaps give a graphical example of the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done by a loop over each element and then for each element a loop over the edges. Then for each edge determine the coordinate for a given contour if it cross the edge, i.e. check if the contour takes a value in the interval spanned by the vertices values. If the contour crosses two edges, then draw the a line between the coordinates between detected crossing points at the edges.

Doing this for all elements will create the contours. It is also an option to refine to a finer mesh via interpolation on each triangle and then use a delaunay triangulations of the refined mesh and then apply the routine as described above for achieving a sufficiently fine resolution.

Comment: The runtime for this is $O(F*n)$, where $F$ is the face number and $n$ is the number of contour, is there anyway to improve on this algorithm's runtime?

Comment: @Graviton: I doen't think you can expect to be much better than linear scaling with problem size...